# scala play unmanaged jar added but import not working

Tags: scala, playframework, jar, sbt

I'm trying to add [Jep](https://github.com/mrj0/jep) to a Scala (2.11.8) Play Framework (2.5.8) project of mine.
As far as I can tell, Sbt can see the unmanaged jar:

```
[play-scala] $ show unmanagedClasspath
[info] List(Attributed(/home/stondo/dev/git/play-dashboard-mongo/lib/jep.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so), Attributed(/home/stondo/dev/git/play-dashboard-mongo/lib/libjep.so), Attributed(/home/stondo/dev/git/play-dashboard-mongo/lib/jep-3.6.0.jar))
```

but when I run a very simple test it fails:

```
[error] cannot create an instance for class IntegrationSpec                                                                                                                                                                      
...
[error]   CAUSED BY java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jep in java.library.path
...
```

Let me mention that running scala -cp /path/to/myjar and then importing Jep, works:

```
scala -cp ./lib/jep-3.6.0.jar
scala> import jep.Jep
import jep.Jep
```

Any ideas about what's going on?
Thanks in advance

Comment: And you flagged this as [python] because?

Comment: just because Jep is python related, but I can see your concern, and perhaps I should've thought twice. Python tag removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a problem of import-not-working. It's a problem of cannot loading the native library. Unlike java libraries, native libraries (jep.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so) must be put in some directory listed in either the PATH environment variable or the "java.library.path" system property.

Comment: Thanks man, that solved the problem! I just add to add to my build.sbt two lines: javaOptions in Test += "-Djava.library.path=/path/to/lib"
javaOptions in Compile += "-Djava.library.path=/path/to/lib"

Comment: above it's "had to add"